# How to add constrains in vertically aligned UIButtons in swift 2?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uibutton

I have three vertically aligned UIButton A,B,C in viewController. I want to add constrains programmatically in button C such that if i hide/remove button B then C should be in the place of B, if button B appears then C should be next to B. How can i add constrains programmatically.

Comment: I understand the first part but the second C should be next to B or under B?...

Comment: Is it good if I don't use constraints, but I get to the result needed?

Comment: I'm working on it.

Comment: Do you add the buttons programmatically?? If so, I cannot help you. If you add the buttons from the storyboard I will help you.

Comment: try using stackview and u can simply use button.hidden=true. it is the easiest way to achieve what you want.

Comment: i made all buttons programmatically, all buttons are vertically aligned if button B is present then my sequence is A-B-C, if button B is not present then A-C, that is what i'm trying to make.

Answer (score 1):

---

**NOTE:** This version doesn't use constraints applied programmatically, but gets to the desired result!

---

My `Main.storyboard File` looks like this:

[image: Main.storyboard]

---

**Explanation:**  I have 3 button outlets and one button action. When you press the *hide Button B*  button, `Button C` disappears, but `Button B` receives the title `Button C` and also its action, and *hide Button B* becomes *show Button B*. The actions of the buttons are `Apressed()`, `Bpressed()` and `Cpressed()`. You can add your own code in there, I have just gave `backgroundColor()` as an example.

---

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var buttonA: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonB: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonC: UIButton!
    var i = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        buttonA.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.Apressed), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
        buttonB.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.Bpressed), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
        buttonC.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.Cpressed), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    @IBAction func hideB(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        if i == 0{
        buttonC.isHidden = true
        buttonB.setTitle("Button C", for: .normal)
        buttonB.removeTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.Bpressed), for: .touchUpInside)
        buttonB.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.Cpressed), for: .touchUpInside)
        i += 1
        sender.setTitle("Show Button B", for: .normal)
        }
        else if i == 1{
            buttonC.isHidden = false
            buttonB.removeTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.Cpressed), for: .touchUpInside)
            buttonB.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.Bpressed), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
            buttonB.setTitle("Button B", for: .normal)
            i = 0
            sender.setTitle("Hide Button B", for: .normal)

        }

    }
    func Apressed(){
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red()
    }
    func Bpressed(){
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.green()
    }
    func Cpressed(){
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow()
    }



}
```

---

### The Final Result:

[image: Simulator Final Result]

---

Answer (score 0):

I do suggest you to set first all the constraints via Storyboard (if possibile) of the 3 buttons and then set also a fixed height via constraints too.

Than you can create an `@IBOutlet weak var bHeight: NSLayoutConstrait!` and attach it to your `UIButton B Height` in storyboard ( you can see how to do that also directly from Storyboard from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15893022/setting-constraints-programatically)  ).

Then if you force `bHeight.constant = 0` you should be able to achieve your goal.